# Ckeditor - i need to add a <br> tag after an image is inserted into the page - help

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm simply trying to add a break tag after any image that is inserted into a ckeditor wysiwyg box and having no luck.  I know this is not ideal, but this is what has to be done.  I've searched and played around but can't seem to get anything to work.  Anyone have any ideas?

The problem that's occurring for one of my users is that sometimes when they add an image they can't get the cursor to appear after the image so they are unable to add any kind of text or anything after.

Any other ideas on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

To insert a `<br />` tag instead of a new `<p>`, hold Shift while pressing Enter. I would also recommend to your users to float their images, as the text will wrap around floated images.

Comment: I can't depend on what the user does.  I need to automatically add a <br /> after the insertion of an image into the editor to bring the cursor down to the next line after the image.  Boss is adamant about this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a reported bug with ckeditor.  Hopefully they fix it soon.